# is there an anchor task that contains bundleDebug and bundleRelease in Android Gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Gradle plugin, task "assemble" is an anchor task that contains assembleDebug and assembleRelease. Is there a similar anchor task that contains bundleDebug and bundleRelease. I currently have following build script where a task depends on bundleDebug:

```
android.libraryVariants.all {
    variant -> variant.javaCompile.classpath += configurations.provided
}
task removeCameraApiJar(dependsOn: 'bundleDebug') << {
    FileCollection outputs = tasks['bundleDebug'].getOutputs().getFiles()
    outputs.each {
        File file ->
            println file.name
    }
    println 'removeCameraApiJar'
}
task assemble.dependsOn(removeCameraApiJar)
```

However if I replace bundleDebug with just "bundle", the script would fail with following message:

> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':camerasupport:removeCameraApiJar'.
>
> > Task with path 'bundle' not found in project ':camerasupport'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem as though the Android plugin creates such a task. You could however do something like

```
task removeCameraApiJar(dependsOn: tasks.matching { it.name.startsWith('bundle') })
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of the gradle android plugin (1.5.0), the bundle task can be found as a property ("packageLibrary") of the variant output :

```
android.libraryVariants.all {
    variant -> 
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
    FileCollection outputs = 
    output.packageLibrary.getOutputs().getFiles()
    }
}
```

prinln output.packageLibrary.name will yield "bundle"+buildVariant.